# Debugging crazy React library line of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to make use of this react plugin thats kind of like Chosen for React. Here's a link to the full repo: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select. I'm getting errors on a crazy line in there and am having trouble figuring out what the problem is and how to fix it. I'm running React .11.2. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the line it appears to be failing on:

```
React.createElement("span", { className: "Select-clear", title: this.props.multi ? this.props.clearAllText : this.props.clearValueText, "aria-label": this.props.multi ? this.props.clearAllText : this.props.clearValueText, onMouseDown: this.clearValue, onClick: this.clearValue, dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: "&times;" } })
```

And gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Inside of:

```
// Specifying arguments isn't necessary since we just use apply anyway, but it
// makes it clear for those actually consuming this API.
function createDescriptor(type, props, children) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return type.apply(null, args);
}
```

Which is in `react-with-addons.js` and its the `type` var that is failing. Its receiving a string `"span"`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createElement` was introduced in 0.12, so there's no chance of getting it to work in 0.11 without backporting it.

To do so, it'd look like this:

```
React.createElement = function(tag){
   var rest = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
   if (typeof tag === 'function') {
       return tag.apply(undefined, rest);
   }
   else if (typeof tag === 'string' && React.DOM[tag]) {
       return React.DOM[tag].apply(undefined, rest);
   }
   else {
       console.error('React.createElement() expects a HTML tag name or ' 
           + 'component as the first argument, but got (%s) %s',
           String(tag), 
           typeof tag
       );
       return null;
   }
};

// partially applies createElement
React.createFactory = function(tag){
   return React.createElement.bind(null, tag);
}
```

The final case will also error on e.g. 'my-custom-element', which isn't supported at all in 0.11 and there's no way to fake it.